# How to deserialize this xml to objects?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm fetching data in the format of this:

```
<ReplyUserAccount xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" requestid="" version="1.0" xmlns="url">
  <Sender partnerid="xx">xx</Sender>
  <Users>
    <User method="GET" ResultCode="OK" Description="">
      <Guid>xx</Guid>
      <FirstName>xx</FirstName>
      <LastName>xx</LastName>
      <Phone>xx</Phone>
      <Mobile>xx</Mobile>
      <Email>xx</Email>
      <EmplNo>xx</EmplNo>
      <TacPermission />
      <InvPermission>xx</InvPermission>
      <CustomerId>xx</CustomerId>
    </User>
    </Users>
</ReplyUserAccount>
```

With the following C# objects:

```
    [XmlRoot("ReplyUserAccount")]
    public class ReplyUserAccount
    {
        [XmlElement("Users")]
        public Users Users{ get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("Users")]
    public class Users
    {
        [XmlElement("User")]
        public List<User> UserList{ get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType("User")]
    public class User
    {
        [XmlElement("EmplNo")]
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Guid")]
        public string Guid { get; set; } = null;
        [XmlElement("Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null;
    }
```

And the following deserializing:

```
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReplyUserAccount));
var content = xdoc.ToString();
TextReader reader = new StringReader(content);
var res = (ReplyUserAccount)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

But I get the following error:
`InvalidOperationException: <ReplyUserAccount xmlns='xxx'> was not expected`.

I'm a little bit lost as to how to properly deserialize this specific xml data. Any and all help with regards to this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you create the classes?  Have you tried using the "Paste XML as Classes" feature in Visual Studio?  (

Comment: @Neil I craeted them myself.
I had no idea there was such a feature in Visual Studio! I will check it out thank you!

Comment: @Neil It seems this feature is missing in VS2019 and there doesn't seem to be any fixes incoming as of now. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/580529/the-visual-studio-2019-paste-special-option-is-not.html

Comment: I'm on Vs2019 Community Edition (this week's update) and it's there (and it works) for me.

Comment: @Neil Where do you find the option?

Comment: Copy the XML to the clipboard, then in VS, choose Edit/Paste Special/Paste XML as classes.

Comment: @Neil I found the option but using that option still gives the error `InvalidOperationException: <ReplyUserAccount xmlns='xx'> was not expected.`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error, You have to remove **xmlns** and **xsi** in xml text before deserialize. You can remove **xmlns** and **xsi** like this:

```
var content = xdoc.ToString();
string strXMLPattern = @"xmlns(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""|xsi(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""";
content = Regex.Replace(content, strXMLPattern, "");
```

Therefore the method should be as follows

```
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReplyUserAccount));
var content = xdoc.ToString();
string strXMLPattern = @"xmlns(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""|xsi(:\w+)?=""([^""]+)""";
content = Regex.Replace(content, strXMLPattern, "");
TextReader reader = new StringReader(content);
var res = (ReplyUserAccount)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```